# Submit multiple form fields for each file in FineUploader

Tags: fine-uploader

I have managed to get fineuploader working fine, including the submission of other form elements.

I now have a requirement to have separate form elements for each file that is submitted. 
If you know how youtube works, then you will see how each video gets additional form fields, then you can fill in while the video is still uploading. I can handle the additional form fields being submitted without any problems (using a separate ajax call if necessary), but how do I associate the form fields with the different files?

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Wait until the user has filled out the file-specific fields (or wait until they press an "upload" button), call the `setParams` method on the Fine Uploader instance (passing the params as an object), and then ask Fine Uploader to upload the files.  This assumes the `autoUpload` option is set to "false", and you have a button that starts that uploads which calls the `uploadStoredFiles` method on the uploader instance.
2. Add logic to your web app that submits these additional form fields outside of Fine Uploader on demand, assuming you want to be able to have users enter this data after the upload has already started or completed.  In that case, you can pass the file's UUID (created by Fine Uploader) along with the parameters/form values.  Fine Uploader will already send a UUID for each file along with each upload request, so you will need to track this server-side in order to connect the file with your future request.

Comment: Hey Ray. Thanks for the response. Option 2 sounds like it makes the most sense to me. The only part that I can't figure out from the docs - where in the client do I get the UUID? I am using the core uploader and completely customised all the callbacks. As far as I can see, the `complete` event accepts the file id (int, not uuid), filename and response

Comment: You can obtain the UUID for any file client-side via the `getUuid` method.  Have a look at the [methods documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/methods.html) for more details.