# FineUploader - get metadata during upload and store it

Tags: metadata, fine-uploader

I am using FineUploader and it works just fine for my application needs. The files end up where I need them etc.

However once the file is uploaded, I really don't know what the file actually is. For instance the file could be a resume, a cover letter, a release of information, etc. For that I will need to "attach" additional metadata that relates to that file.

Is there a way to add some sort of a select box, where the user will select a category (before the upload process begins) so that the file can be identified by that category? The filename, size and other information gathered during the upload process are already stored in the database.

Any pointers are more than appreciated.

Edit: Duplicate [Submit multiple form fields for each file in FineUploader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619601/submit-multiple-form-fields-for-each-file-in-fineuploader)

Comment: Are you thinking of one select element per file, with Fine Uploader's autoUpload mode set to false?  The user submits files, then chooses a type for each file, then clicks a button to upload all files?

Comment: I have the autoUpload already to false because I want the users to have the ability to edit the file name. I was thinking either what you are suggesting or a select box per file uploaded (next to the file name) and one submit does all.

Comment: Your approach sounds identical to my suggestion.  I'm not sure what the difference is.  I'll proceed with an answer outlining my suggestion a bit more.

Comment: Seems like this is explained in an existing SO question.  I'll mark this as a duplicate, which will link to that question/answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submit multiple form fields for each file in FineUploader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619601/submit-multiple-form-fields-for-each-file-in-fineuploader)

Comment: Thank you @RayNicholus. That is a great pointer which will do what I need.